# Elements of combinatorial analysis

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

[image: Elements of combinatorics]

How to use the given hint to answer this question?

More Context for this question:

This problem refers to the classical occupancy problem (Boltzmann-Maxwell statistics): that is,  r balls are distributed among n cells  and each of the $n^r$ possible distributions has probability $n^{-r}$

When I insert r=3,n=2 as per Henry"s comment,I got '?' as an answer. How is that?

[image: result] [image: result]

More information:

[image: Maxwell-Boltzmann]
[image: MaxwellBoltzmann1]

Comment: What are the "cells"? Can you add more context? What have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What have you tried? Do you have any ideas of your own? Once we have a better idea exactly where you're struggling, we can help you better ^_^

Comment: @LukeCollins, I didn't understand what is A(r, n+1) ,A(r, n) , A(r-k, n), A(r, n+k), v, where n=cells ,r = balls

Comment: @LukeCollins, I think A(r, n+1), A(r,n), A(r, n+k)  means number of distributions leaving none of the n +1 , n, n+k cells empty respectively

Comment: So for example if $r=3,n=2$, you have $A(n,r)=6$ since $(\{a,b\},\{c\}),$ $(\{a,c\},\{b\}),$ $(\{a\},\{b,c\}),$  $(\{b,c\},\{a\}),$ $(\{b\},\{a,c\}),$ $(\{c\},\{a,b\})$ all work, while $(\{a,b,c\},\{\})$ and $(\{\},\{a,b,c\})$ do not as a cell is empty

Comment: @Henry, I insert r=3, n=2 in (2) , the result is '?"